# Status of inline type annotations

Tags: php, annotations, phpdocumentor2

I've been using [Eclipse/Zend type annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/defining-a-variable-type-in-comment-ii) for years to help editor's code intellisense where regular phpDocumentor docblocks do not suffice:

```
/* @var $db PDO */
$db->exec('DELETE FROM pending_jobs');
```

… but I'm not sure they're widely used nowadays.

PHP-FIG proposed a [new syntax for this feature](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#722-var) in the context of *PSR-5 PHPDoc Standard*:

```
/** @var PDO $db Database connection. */
```

… but PSR-5 is [listed as abandoned](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/#abandoned) and as far as I can tell phpDocumentor [hasn't implemented it](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/blob/develop/docs/references/phpdoc/tags/var.rst).

PhpStorm just supports all variations:

```
/* @var $db PDO */
/* @var PDO $db */
/** @var PDO $db */
/** @var $db PDO */
```

Even Zend Framework codebase seems to mix them all.

Is there a widespread syntax or something close to a de-facto standard? Has it been subject to discussions in some major PHP projects?

Comment: Something like this would be opinionated as a result it might be closed.

Comment: @Script47 As long as answers are about what they requested - a standard. Standards are opinionated in themselves but we can quote them without ambiguity

Comment: @Script47 That'd be case if I were asking what's the *best* coding standard. I'm only interested in knowing if this specific issue has been discussed by relevant coding standards or major leagues projects.

Comment: I reject your standards, and substitute my own brand of lunacy!